# Going between sheaves and slices

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, sheaf-theory

(By *sheaf*, I mean a sheaf of sets.)

Let $X$ denote a topological space. If I understand correctly, there seems to be a way of turning sheaves on $X$ into slices of $X$, and vice versa. In particular, I think the following is true:

1. Suppose we have a slice $\pi:E \rightarrow X$ of $X$. Then if I'm not mistaken, the local sections of $\pi$ should organize themselves into a sheaf.
2. Conversely, suppose we have a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$. Then the germs of this sheaf should organize themselves into a slice $\pi:\mathrm{Germ}(\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow X.$

> **Questions.**
>
> **QA.** Is this correct?
>
> **QB.** If so, what is the usual notation for what I'm denoting $\mathrm{Germ}(\mathcal{F})$, and what's the precise way in which all the stalks organize themselves into a single topological space $\mathrm{Germ}(\mathcal{F})$?
>
> **QC.** Are there any further basic facts about the relationship between sheaves and slices that are really essential to understanding what's going on here?

Comment: What do you mean by slice ? You should look at what is an "étalé space". But you don't need étalé space for doing sheaf theory. Anyway if "slice" means local homeomorphism then QA is correct. QC : no you don't.

Comment: @N.H., hey sorry for the late reply. [I just mean this.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category). So basically, I just mean that $\pi$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Don't worry. Thanks for the link. Most people use sheaf as a way of compute cohomology (e.g in algebraic geometry) so in this setting the "étalé" viewpoint is not so useful. If you are interested in logic or category, probably it's more useful (and it's a nice construction anyways), I'm sure there should be something about it in "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic" by MacLane.

Comment: @N.H., thanks. $\;$